# Random Number Generation - Not same Results for MT and SMFT

Tags: c#, random

Here is my question: I have random numbers generated from MT19937 (32 bit words) and random numbers provided by the SMFT (SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister) with same period and in 32-bit word length configuration. 
Moreover, I have generated the values with the same seed (=0). The results are however different !
Could anyone explain me, how that is possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SIMD-oriented Mersenne Twister webpage](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~%20m-mat/MT/SFMT/):

> SFMT is much faster than MT, in most platforms. Not only the speed, but also the dimensions of equidistributions at v-bit precision are improved.

If anything is improved it **has** to have different results even for the same seed. I would assume it's a slightly different algorithm optimized for modern CPUs that shares the same basic principle with the MT19937.

Comment: Right. I dont know the exact difference, but `SFMT` internally produces 128 bit integer - which is probably mapped to 32 bit number.

Comment: Thank you both. You are right. Moreover, the recursion function  itself is quite different between the two version so it will provide different results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `SFMT` has better equi-distribution property and faster recovery from `0`s. Therefore its implementation is different from `MT`